# How to call method which takes an array using reflection

Tags: java, arrays

Consider the following complete Java program.

```
public class Reflection
{

  static class A
  {
    public void useArray( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "Args are " + Arrays.toString( args ) );
    }
  }

  public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
  { 
    Method m = A.class.getMethod( "useArray", String[].class );
    m.invoke( new A(), new String[] { "Hi" } );
  }

}
```

Trying to run this, you get an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
```

If instead of using only one String in the array passed to `invoke` you pass more than one, then you get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
```

So, clearly, because `invoke`'s signature is:

```
invoke(java.lang.Object obj, java.lang.Object... args)
```

when I call `invoke` using an array, the call is getting "translated" to:

```
m.invoke( new A(), "Hi" );
```

How to make Java understand that I do want my array to be passed into `invoke` intact??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

##### Some general info

The `Method#invoke` has two parameters

1. `Object obj` which takes object on which method should be invoked
2. `Object... args` which takes Object[] array *holding all arguments* for method.

So if we want to call method like `methodName(foo, bar, baz)` the `Object... args` should end up becoming `new Object[]{foo, bar, baz}`.

Similarly since `useArray` expects ***one argument*** which is `String[]` array itself, the `Object... args` should end up *wrapping* that array and becoming `new Object[]{ new String[]{"Hi"} }`

#### Solution

We can achieve that via explicitly writing

```
m.invoke(new A(), new Object[]{ new String[]{ "Hi" } });
//                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^----------------------^
```

OR

by telling compiler to treat `String[]` as *single `Object`* to let varargs wrap it inside `new Object[]{...}` array for us. We can achieve that by casting

```
m.invoke(new A(), (Object) new String[]{"Hi"});
//                ^^^^^^^^
```

#### Problem with your code

The `String[]` array *is subtype* of `Object[]`. This means that ***it ends up being assigned as value of `args`*** like

```
Object... args = new String[]{"Hi"};
```

instead of being wrapped by Object[] array like

```
Object... args = new Object[]{ new String[]{"Hi"} };
```

Because of that you end up with code representing **`new A().useArray("Hi")`**.

But since `useArray` method expects `String[]` array and not `String` you are getting `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch` exception.